# Cross Domain Requests by id

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm trying to display a collage of images from other sites on my webpage.  It works fine if I know the direct link because I can set the img src. However if I only know the name of the page and the id of the image on that page can make some jQuery call to retrieve the src.

Something like this, but called on another page:

```
var imageSource = $("#pictureid").attr("src");
```

Comment: You could try http://easyxdm.net/wp/, but I'm not sure if it works for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want would involve making an AJAX call to that other site to pull in the HTML, and then look through that to find the `src` attribute of the `img` tag you're interested in. All modern browsers have some sort of Same Origin Policy in place though which forbids this - you cannot make AJAX calls to anything outside the current document's domain (that is, a script running in a page on example.org cannot make AJAX calls to foobar.com).

This means that you have to resort to server-side techniques: In the server-side language of your choice, load the HTML from the external page (most environments have bindings into libcurl, which was designed to do exactly this) and then parse that to find the image. Once you have the URL, you can easily insert it into your dynamic HTML.

That said, deep-linking images without permission kind of violates netiquette, and it may even be illegal, depending on the jurisdiction you're in (you're abusing someone else's server to provide bandwidth to your visitors, after all, something that might fall under the definition of illegal hacking in some jurisdictions); the nice thing to do is to pull the image itself in as well and host a copy on your own server, so that you are using your own bandwidth to serve it. And of course, respect the copyright and, if any, licensing terms, of the images you use.

Comment: Thank you for the legal information,  something i hadn't thought about yet.The project is actually a browser extension so the html is hosted on the client side as opposed to on a server. Given this I am trying to keep things client side.  It seems clumsily to go through a server to access a webpage instead of going directly from the client.

Comment: Well, if the javascript runs in a browser extension, the Same Origin Policy might be less strict, although I have way too little experience with these to tell you anything, really. You might be able to pull it off.

Comment: The chrome extension API makes these things really simple it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Client side javascript isnt designed for this. What you want to do it screen scraping. You can do this in a number of ways, the easiest being Yahoo's YQL and other ways using Node.JS, PHP or your preferred serverside language.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you wish to include an image on your site you need to provide the URL for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this:**

First we need a short server-side script to bounce our request, since AJAX is hindered by the same origin policy. Here's something in PHP:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['url'])) readfile($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Let's say that this is saved at `get.php`. To use it, we just set the url field of the query string with the url of the page we want to get. The script gets all of the HTML from that page and outputs it. For instance, `get.php?url=http://stackoverflow.com/` would get all of the HTML in stackoverfllow's index page.

Next, let's write some jQuery to retrieve the src of the specified picture at the url.  Like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.pics.com/';
var selector = '#pic8';

$.get('get.php', { url: url }, function(htmlResponse) {
    var pic = $(htmlResponse).find(selector);
    alert(pic.attr('src');
}, 'html');
```

That should work.